# Cannot get apa6 style to work in (MiK)TeX

Tags: miktex, texmaker, apa6

I am a new LaTeX user, and I followed some guides on the internet to set up MiKTeX + Texmakerx on Windows Vista. As I am doing a PhD in Psychology, I wanted to use the new [APA6 class](http://ctan.mackichan.com/macros/latex/contrib/apa6/apa6.pdf). So I opened the MiKTeX Package Manager in admin mode and installed `apa6`. Next I did a refresh FNDB. However, when I make a new LaTeX document with

```
\documentclass[man]{apa6}
```

in the preamble, I get the following output:

```
File 'apa6.cls' not found.
```

Can someone point me in the right direction as to what I am doing wrong?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. Upvoting is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you.

Comment: @Tim open a command window (windows sym + r, type cmd + enter) and type `kpsewhich apa6.cls` Whats the answer of kpathsea?

Comment: when I type kpsewhich apa6.cls it returns nothing. However, typing, for example, kpsewhich apa.cls returns c:/program files/Miktex 2.9/tex/latex/apa/apa.cls.

Comment: @Tim Then the class was either not installed or MiKTeX did not update the FNDB it uses for you as user.

Comment: If a package in miktex is installed with the package manager it should work. There should be no need to click of some additional buttons. If is doesn't work this normally means that either the user is doing something wrong (e.g. a typo) or the package is defective (that happens). In this case it is the second: apa6 of miktex contains only a pdf and a readme, no apa6.cls. Someone should make a bug report in the miktex bug tracker.

Comment: @Ulrike: That explains a lot! Are there any alternatives that I can use to install apa6 any other way?

Comment: Well you always can install a package manually. Get apa6.dtx from CTAN, put in in an empty folder and compile it with pdflatex. Then move the generated files to a local texmf tree and update the FNDB. http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=installthings. But you should make a bug report in any case so that the faulty package can be corrected. Btw: There are other files missing beside the cls.

Answer (score 3):

Just try to refresh the FNDB also as user.

**Edit:** After reading Ulrike's comment I tried to get it to work. A very simple workaround would be that you google for apa6.cls and save the file into you present LaTeX project folder where the main latex file is located without touching the MiKTeX configuration. That have the advantage that your project compile on every computer you are working on.

Note: If you use the *man* or *doc* documentclass option define the command `\shorttitle` (i.e. `\shorttitle{Title of the publication}`) in the preamble of your document. If the command is undefined the compilation stops with the error message:

```
"Undefined control sequence.
\@shorttitle"
```

If the MiKTeX bug is fixed you can delete the apa6.cls from your project folder.

Answer (score 0):

I could get it to work by extracting the `apa6.cls` with typing

```
pdflatex apa6.dtx
```

in my command window. It then compiles and creates the `apa6.cls`. If you then move the files to `...\MiKTEX\tex\latex\apa6\`