# How do I write a paper using APA6 format?

Tags: texlive, apa6

I'm trying to write a paper, and the format must adhere to APA style, 6th edition.    I've found that I should use `\documentclass{apa6}` to do this.  Well, I tried, and I get :

```
File 'apa6.cls' not found.
```

Of course I then saw [Cannot get apa6 style to work in (MiK)TeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44098/cannot-get-apa6-style-to-work-in-miktex), and decided I could install it manually (the only response that made any sense to me.)  Well, I found [apa6.dtx](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/apa6), I put it in an empty directory, and ran "pdflatex apa6.dtx".  Here's what I see:

> ```
> Generating file(s) ./apa6.cls 
>
> Processing file apa6.dtx (class) -> apa6.cls
> File apa6.dtx ended by \endinput.
> Lines  processed: 4034
> Comments removed: 1379
> Comments  passed: 53
> Codelines passed: 2560
>
>
> Generating file(s) ././config/APAamerican.txt ././config/APAbritish.txt ././con
> fig/APAdutch.txt ././config/APAenglish.txt ././config/APAgerman.txt ././config/
> APAngerman.txt ././config/APAgreek.txt ././config/APAczech.txt ././config/APAen
> dfloat.cfg 
> ! I can't write on file `././config/APAamerican.txt'.
> <to be read again> 
>                    \edef 
> l.142 }
>
> (Press Enter to retry, or Control-D to exit; default file extension is `.tex')
> Please type another output file name:
> ```

If I cancel it, it still generates an apa6.cls file, but I then get this error when I try to use it:

> ```
> ! LaTeX Error: Option clash for package geometry.
>
> See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation. Type  H <return>  for immediate help.  ...                                    
>
>                                                    l.3 \usepackage
>                [pdftex]{graphicx}
> ```

What should I do?

By the way, I'm running Ubuntu with the `texlive-full` package installed.

Comment: Turns out it produced `apa6.cls` anyway.